# TextMate frozen attempting to open a large file

Tags: textmate

I attempted to open a large javascript file with TextMate and it is now frozen.  I have tried closing and reopening TextMate but it continues to freeze due to the recently opened file.  Is there a way to reset/clear the recently opened files in TextMate?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you open TextMate from the Finder with a double click **and** hold shift pressed, you will get this dialog:

[image: Disable session dialog]

"Disable" will do exactly what you want, "Restore Documents" will continue to restore them.

Answer (score 3):

Try [setting this parameter](http://programmingthomas.com/blog/2014/1/3/prevent-textmate-from-resuming-its-state):

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDisableSessionRestore 1
```

Comment: Just for the record: This works, but disables sessions permanently. One would set it to 0 / false afterwards to get the default behavior back.

Comment: The other answer didn't work for me (textmate 2.0.23, Mac OS Monterey). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/textmate/textmate/blob/master/Frameworks/Preferences/src/Keys.mm

shows the user "defaults" strings to use.

In your/my case (2.0.23 on 12.6.7) use:

- "defaults write com.macromates.textmate disableSessionRestore 1" to disable
- start textmate again in CLI "open /Applications/TextMate.app"
- close app
- "defaults write com.macromates.textmate disableSessionRestore 0" to re-enable default behavior
- open app again